# How can I see what query is emitted by the query parser?

Tags: postgresql

Consider this snippet:

```
create table tbl_1(name text);
create table tbl_2(name text);

create function my_insert(_name text) returns text
    language sql
as $$
   insert into tbl_2(name)
   values (_name);
   select _name;
$$;

explain analyse
with x as (select name from tbl_1)
   ,y as (select my_insert(x.name) from x)
select 0
;
```

returns

```
Result  (cost=12.72..12.72 rows=1 width=4) (actual time=0.001..0.001 rows=1 loops=1)
  CTE x
    ->  Seq Scan on tbl_1  (cost=0.00..12.72 rows=1360 width=32) (never executed)
Planning Time: 0.053 ms 
Execution Time: 0.013 ms
```

Now I can understand why the clause `x` isn't being executed (and also `y` of course), but the plan doesn't mention anything about what happened to clause `y`.

This leads me to suspect that the query parser is emitting a query that doesn't contain the clause `y`.

How can I confirm this? How can I see what the parser is emitting here? Alternatively, how can see what query the planner evaluated?

Comment: If `x` was never executed, `y` cannot have been executed, because it uses `x`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *This leads me to suspect that the query parser is emitting a query
>   that doesn't contain the clause y.*

The query parser emits query trees and the query planner emits plans. Both can be shown in more detail with the `debug_print_parse` and `debug_print_plan` settings.
From the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/querytree.html):

> Now what is a query tree? It is an internal representation of an SQL
>   statement where the single parts that it is built from are stored
>   separately. These query trees can be shown in the server log if you
>   set the configuration parameters debug_print_parse,
>   debug_print_rewritten, or debug_print_plan

In the case of the query in the question, `y` is apparently eliminated. It's the work of the planner, not of the parser.
The log output with `debug_print_parse` would show it, because that's before it gets eliminated, contrary to the output with `debug_print_plan`, in which it should not be present.

However, the result of `EXPLAIN` with no mention of the evaluation of `y` should be a sufficient proof that the planner has eliminated it.